# What is ADDS, ADFS, ADMS, AD PKI, ADRMS, AD CS, DIAD, ADH? Explain me with an example so that I remember

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, active-directory

It is related to Microsoft Azure, azure related technologies.

I want to get a basic overview of the entire azure related technologies. It confuses me a lot. Explain me so that I get a thorough insight of azure related techniques such that I can teach the same to others as well.

Comment: That's is a lot you're asking for, we can't possibly explain all that with examples. Try https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/products as a starting point.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

as peter mentioned your ask is big and this really is not a programming question too, and SO doesn't work on providing recommendations. lemme tell you about the things you asked, plz visit documentation for detailed info

Think of ADDS as the boss that manages users, computers, and groups in a network. It's like the central phonebook for a company. For example, it keeps track of who's in the office, who's using which computer, and who belongs to which team.

ADFS is like the VIP pass for accessing different parties. It allows you to use your credentials from one place (like your company) to access resources in another place (like a partner company). So, it's like using your work badge to enter a different office building.

ADMS helps in managing and organizing the directory. It's like having a very goood organizer for your phonebook, making sure everything is in the right place and easy to find.

AD PKI is like the bouncer for your network hehe, making sure that only the right people (or computers) get in. It manages digital certificates, ensuring secure communication. Imagine it as giving each team member a secret handshake to access the company's secret club.

ADRMS is your data bodyguard. It helps protect sensitive information by controlling who can view, print, or forward certain files.

AD CS is the certificate maker. It creates and manages digital certificates, ensuring that when someone presents their badge (certificate), you know it's legit. It's like getting an official stamp on your passport when traveling.

DIAD is the architect designing how everything fits together in your directory. It ensures that your phonebook is well-organized, efficient, and serves its purpose. juz like a interior designer for your directory structure.

ADH is like the doctor for your directory, making sure it's in good shape. It monitors, diagnoses, and ensures the overall health of your Active Directory.